# Calling the more-specific overloaded function from a reference to a base class

Tags: c++, overriding, overload-resolution, visitor-pattern

First of all, sorry for the cryptic title, this is not easy to explain.

What I want to do is to implement the Visitor pattern in C++ using overloaded functions. This is my situation:

1. I have a collection of *parsers*. Each parser returns a specific derived type of `Element`. Basically, I end up with a polymorphic collection of `Element`s, all of them implementing the `visit(Visitor&)` function.
2. I have some analyzers (`Visitor`s). Each visitor is only interested in a few specific `Element` derived classes.
3. The base class for `Visitor` has an empty implementation for `visit(Element&)` that receives as the argument an `Element` reference.
4. Each `Visitor` derived class implements the `visit` functions for the specific element types it's interested in. That is, I'd have a `visit(DerivedElement&)` overloaded function in the `DerivedVisitor` class.
5. When calling `accept(Visitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }`, the function being called should be the more specific one. That is, if `v` is a `DerivedVisitor` and `accept` is implemented in a `DerivedElement`, I'd like the function `visit(DerivedElement&)` to be called.

Some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Visitor
{
    public:
        virtual void visit(class BaseElement& e);
};

class BaseElement
{
    public:
        virtual void accept(Visitor &v)
        {
            cout << "accept on BaseElement" << endl;
            v.visit(*this);
        }

        virtual void doThings()
        {
            cout << "doThings on BaseElement" << endl;
        }
};

void Visitor::visit(BaseElement& e)
{
    cout << "visit on Visitor" << endl;
    e.doThings();
}

class DerivedElement : public BaseElement
{
    public:
        virtual void accept(Visitor &v)
        {
            cout << "accept on DerivedElement" << endl;
            v.visit(*this);
        }

        virtual void doThings()
        {
            cout << "doThings on DerivedElement" << endl;
        }
};

class DerivedVisitor : public Visitor
{
    public:
        void visit(BaseElement& e)
        {
            cout << "visit-BaseElement on DerivedVisitor" << endl;
            e.doThings();
        }

        void visit(DerivedElement &e)
        {
            cout << "visit-DerivedElement on DerivedVisitor" << endl;
            e.doThings();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    BaseElement eBase;
    DerivedElement eDeriv;
    BaseElement& eDerivAsBase = eDeriv;
    Visitor vBase;
    DerivedVisitor vDeriv;

    cout << "Visiting a BaseElement with the base visitor:" << endl;
    eBase.accept(vBase);
    cout << endl << "Visiting a BaseElement with the derived visitor:" << endl;
    eBase.accept(vDeriv);

    cout << endl << "Visiting Base and Derived elements with the derived visitor" << endl;
    eBase.accept(vDeriv);
    eDeriv.accept(vDeriv);

    cout << endl << "Visiting Base element as Derived reference" << endl;
    eDerivAsBase.accept(vBase);
    eDerivAsBase.accept(vDeriv);

}
```

This is the output

```
Visiting a BaseElement with the base visitor:
accept on BaseElement
visit on Visitor
doThings on BaseElement

Visiting a BaseElement with the derived visitor:
accept on BaseElement
visit-BaseElement on DerivedVisitor
doThings on BaseElement

Visiting Base and Derived elements with the derived visitor
accept on BaseElement
visit-BaseElement on DerivedVisitor
doThings on BaseElement
accept on DerivedElement
visit-BaseElement on DerivedVisitor (!)
doThings on DerivedElement

Visiting Base element as Derived reference
accept on DerivedElement
visit on Visitor
doThings on DerivedElement
accept on DerivedElement
visit-BaseElement on DerivedVisitor (!)
doThings on DerivedElement
```

Lines marked with *(!)* are the ones that I'd want to change. Those lines should be "visit-DerivedElement on DerivedVisitor".

Is this possible? Seeing that C++ doesn't implement [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) it seems difficult and I'm probably asking for the impossible. However, I'd really like to see what alternatives do I have, as writing empty `accept(DerivedElementN&)` methods for each one of the derived elements I have doesn't seem the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a great deal of dynamic indirection here. So you're going to need to construct your visitors that way too.

```
 struct BaseVisitor {
     std::unordered_map<std::type_info, std::function<void(BaseElement&)>> types;
     template<typename D, typename F> void AddOverload(F f) {
         types[typeid(D)] = [=](BaseElement& elem) {
             f(static_cast<D&>(elem));
         };
     }
     virtual void visit(BaseElement& elem) {
         if (types.find(typeid(elem)) != types.end())
             types[typeid(elem)](elem);
     }
 }; 
 struct DerivedVisitor : BaseVisitor {
     DerivedVisitor() {
         AddOverload<DerivedElement>([](DerivedElement& e) {
         });
         //... etc
     }
 };
```

The core issue is that you can't use templates as long as you need that dynamic indirection. All you can do is offer an extra layer of type safety and convenience (and potentially speed) over spamming `dynamic_cast`.

Just as a brief note, the above code may not work quite off the bat- there's some fun with typeid to references or `const` or someshit like that that may cause the type lookups to fail when they should succeed.

There are other techniques that can be applied that can remove that limitation if it's important for you, but you might want to stick with dynamic_cast because it's hilarious but awful.

Comment: I see, thanks for the idea. I think that I'll end up with more or less informed casts seeing that there's no good "elegant" solutions. Thanks nevertheless for the interest.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**

Change your post title to "How to implement specialization with the visitor pattern".

**Note:**
You forgot to use the `virtual` keyword in the `DerivedVisitor` class.

**Answer**

You are using 2 features that does not mix well:

Method Overriding ("virtual"). In which, methods from related classes, and the same id., have the same parameters.

```
class Visitor
{
    public:
        virtual void visit(BaseElement& e)
        {
          // print element value to console
        }
};

class DerivedVisitor : public Visitor
{
    public:
        virtual void visit(BaseElement& e)
        {
          // save element value into file
        }
};
```

Method Overloading. In which, methods methods from related classes, and the same id.,have the different parameters.

```
class Visitor
{
    public:
        void visit(BaseElement& e)
        {
          // ...
        }
};

class DerivedVisitor : public Visitor
{
    public:
        void visit(BaseElement& e)
        {
          // ...
        }

        void visit(DerivedElement& e)
        {
          // ...
        }
};
```

Since, you do not show enough source code, I assume you are passing a parameter as a `Element&`, even if it was created as a `DerivedElement&`, so the compiler calls the `void visit(BaseElement& e)`, instead of `void visit(DerivedElement& e)`.

I also, note that you use "references", instead of pointers. It maybe possible that the compiler casts your `DerivedElement` to `BaseElement`. I suggest, use "pointers", instead.

When using polymorphism, is it better not to use "Method Overloading", and stick to "Method Overriding", because, the compiler always call the "virtual" or "overriden" method.

```
class BaseElement
{
    public:
        virtual void accept(Visitor &v)
        {
            cout << "accept on BaseElement" << endl;
            v.visit(*this);
        }

        virtual void doThings()
        {
          cout << "doThings on BaseElement" << endl;
        }
};

class FooElement: BaseElement
{
    public:
        virtual void accept(Visitor &v)
        {
            cout << "accept on FooElement" << endl;
            v.visit(*this);
        }

        virtual void doThings()
        {
          cout << "doThings on FooElement" << endl;
        }
};

class BarElement: BaseElement
{
    public:
        virtual void accept(Visitor &v)
        {
            cout << "accept on BarElement" << endl;
            v.visit(*this);
        }

        virtual void doThings()
        {
          cout << "doThings on BarElement" << endl;
        }
};

class Visitor
{
    public:
        void visit(BaseElement* e)
        {
            cout << "visit Any Element on Visitor" << endl;
            e.doThings();
        }
};

class DerivedVisitor : public Visitor
{
    public:
        void visit(BaseElement* e)
        {
            cout << "visit Any Element on DerivedVisitor" << endl;
            e.doThings();
        }
};

int main (...)
{
  BaseElement* e1 = new FooElement();
  BaseElement* e2 = new BarElement();
  BaseVisitor* v = new DerivedVisitor();

  v->visit(e1);
  v->visit(e2);

  free v();
  free e2();
  free e1();
} // int main (...)
```

Note:
I'm skipping most of the visitor operation, just to simplify the overloading operation.

UPDATE:
With method overriding (A.K.A. "virtual" keyword), specialization is at each `Element` class code, not at the `Visitor` class code. The matching method is called from each derived class.

Cheers.

Comment: The thing is that this is not the same that I proposed. I want specialization which your sample doesn't provide. I'd want to add a different implementation in `DerivedVisitor` for `DerivedElements`s and this doesn't do it. Also, the problem is that the `visit` element is not called from within the `main` function, but from within an `accept` method inside the `BaseElement/DerivedElement` classes, which adds even more difficulty.

Comment: @gjulianm Check the update to my answer. There is only one `visit`method per `visitor`, and the `accept` method is virtual, and "overriden" in each derived or specializated class.

Comment: But it still has the same problem. If you call `e1->accept(*v)`, as `accept` receives a `BaseVisitor` argument, it will call just the general `visit` method that receives `BaseElement`. If you added a `visit(DerivedElement&)` method in the `DerivedVisitor` class, it wouldn't be called from the `accept` mehod, which is what. That is, I actually want to mix method overloading and overriding.

Comment: @gjulianm pardon me, have you actually modified and compiled like the example, or do you suppouse does not work ? I will take the example to my home pc, and verify. In polymorphism, if you pass a parameter to a class instance with parameter declaration like `BaseElement` or `BaseVisitor`, but, the variable was created as`nwe DerivedElement` or `new DerivedVisitor`, the overriden method should be called.

Comment: I've tried it, yes, but the problem can be seen without trying it. My problem is that, if I add a specialized overload `visit(BarElement*)` to `DerivedVisitor`, it will not get called from `accept(Visitor&)` because the C++ compiler uses single dispatch, thus the function called will always be `visit(BaseElement*)` even when derived classes from `Visitor` implement more appropiate and specialized overloads of the `visit` method. Modifying your example (http://pastebin.com/iLyUvYBX) to add the `visit` specialization in `DerivedVisitor` shows that it still does not do multiple dispatch.